# How do I obtain the values from the checkboxes form element?

Tags: javascript

I have put some checkboxes in my custom form.

```
form.elements['zones'] = {
  title: 'Zones',
  type: 'checkboxes',

  options: {
    123: '123',
    456: '456',
    789: '789'
  }
};
```

In my form submission handler, I cannot get the submitted values.

```
function my_module_custom_form_submit(form, form_state) {
  try {
    drupalgap_alert('check values: ' + form_state.values['zones']);
  }
  catch (error) { console.log('my_module_custom_form_submit - ' + error); }
}
```

It just shows *[object Object]*. I tried to use a dump function to print it following http://www.openjs.com/scripts/others/dump_function_php_print_r.php, but it shows nothing. This dump function works when I print `form_state`. The text field and radio button have values, but all my checkboxes show *...*.

Even if I have set the default value in the form, it does not show anything when I print it out.

```
form.elements['zones'] = {
  title: 'Zones',
  type: 'checkboxes',
  options: {
    123: '123',
    456: '456',
    789: '789'
  },
  default_value: {
   456: '456'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `console.log(form_state.values.zones)` to see the data. Essentially it'll look something like this:

```
{
  123: '123',
  456: null,
  789: null
}
```

And this would indicate that only the `123` box is checked. I'm going by memory here, but it should be very obvious which values are checked and which ones are unchecked when looking at the `console.log()` values.

Comment: I opened the javascript console, the output is still [object Object]. I don't see the values. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Since I cannot see the values, can I just use them anyway? How do I write the if statements for this object?

Comment: It sounds like you are developing in a compiled application environment. In that case you can try `console.log(JSON.stringify(form_state.values.zones));`, otherwise I'd recommend developing in a web-app environment, that way you can easily watch the console.log